# how to fix code not hashing every line in file

Tags: python

Im trying to hash each line in a txt file but it will only hash the first line

I tried redirecting print

```py
import hashlib

with open('hash.txt','r+') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        f.write(f'{line} -> {hashlib.sha3_256(line.encode()).hexdigest()}')
f.close()
```

```
output in text 
123
abc
111123 -> a03ab19b866fc585b5cb1812a2f63ca861e7e7643ee5d43fd7106b623725fd67
```

Comment: It looks like your writing into `f` as you iterate through its lines, is this the intended behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing to the same file you are reading from. Try creating new file and writing your result in it

```
with open('hash.txt','r+') as f:
    with open('result.txt', 'w+') as r:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            r.write(f'{line} -> {hashlib.sha3_256(line.encode()).hexdigest()}\n')
```

Also, you don't need to close file if you are using **with**, as it's already getting closed for you